# What is the greatest speed he can reach with an acceleration of 5.00 g before blacking out?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

A jet fighter pilot wishes to accelerate from rest at $5.00$ G to reach Mach-3 (three times the speed of sound) as quickly as possible. Experimental tests reveal that he will black out if this acceleration lasts for more than $5.00\text{s}$ . Use $331\text{m/s}$ for the speed of sound. What is the greatest speed he can reach with an acceleration of $5.00$ G before blacking out?

What I have done is:

Using the formula of acceleration, $a=\frac{Δv}{Δt}=\frac{Δv}{5s}$

Then, I plugged in 5 G into a. $5.00G=\frac{Δv}{5s}$

I assume that the final velocity is $3(331\text{m/s})$ because the fighter pilot wants to reach Mach-3.

So, I have $5.00G=\frac{3(331)−v_0}{5}$. And this is where I am stuck.

Can one tell me how to continue from here, or if I am completely wrong?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that he can reach Mach-3. But you were asked to calculate the speed he can attain before blacking out - starting from rest, so $v_0=0$.

Comment: This is a basic kinematics question. Under constant acceleration, starting from rest, just take your acceleration (5.00 g) and multiply it by the amount of time you are interested in (in this case, the 5.00s before the pilot blacks out). Just don't forget to use the right number for g (you're given speed in m/s).

Comment: an important thing to learn here is that the question has thrown at you a superflous piece of information. The fact that he "wishes" to reach Mach 3 is irrelvent, and you distracted yourself thinking you just had to put that number in an formula someplace.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76486/17609)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I am just going to write this out for completeness's sake.

You are given that

$$v_0 = 0$$

since you are told that the pilot begins from rest. You are then told that he experiences constant acceleration of 5.00 g (since we are dealing with m/s and not ft/s, g = 9.81). Now, using the exact equation from the problem, we can write

$$a = \Delta v/\Delta t = ((v_f - v_0)/\Delta t)$$

Plugging in results in:

$$5.00(9.81) = ((v_f - 0)/(5.00))$$

Which leaves you with a final velocity of $$v_f =  245.25 m/s$$ or, if you are particular about significant digits, $$v_f=245 m/s$$

Notice that this is actually less than Mach one, ultimately suggesting that human beings weren't meant to endure accelerations of 5 g's.